# How to find the minimum support count for vertical apriori?

Tags: data-mining

Eg: Min Support 50%

While changing the given Transaction table(7 Transactionn) to Item Table(6 items) should i take min suppoet count = 50*7/100 or  6*50/100?

Answer (score 0):

It's largely a tradeoff to limit runtime, because you don't want to enumerate all possible itemsets.

The optimum value depends on your data.